# get data from nested json javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have JSON array object but I don't know how to get data from it. I have searched using Iterables & Iterators but I don't understand the concept.

```
{ '-LIDMHr69GLnq1Pyzt6o': 
       { author_avatar: 
          { image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jWM4ghUG930/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/q3nLLgvfOAs/photo.jpg',
            initials: 'UH',
            selection: 'image' 
          },
         author_name: 'AB',
         image: '/assets/images/icons/23.png',
         last_modified: 1542827537242,
         owner_id: 'HauqBY5dDtP0RFhrF1DvEDuFv812',
         team_id: 'private',
         title: 'this is test1'
      },         
      '-LJU_KEYGDv7hRHQ2ABo': 
       { author_avatar: 
          { image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jWM4ghUG930/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/q3nLLgvfOAs/photo.jpg',
            initials: 'UH',
            selection: 'image' 
          },
         author_name: 'AB',
         image: '/assets/images/icons/23.png',
         last_modified: 1542827549341,
         owner_id: 'HauqBY5dDtP0RFhrF1DvEDuFv812',
         team_id: 'private',
         title: 'this is test2' 
        } 
      }
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: What is the expected output? you can either use `Object.keys` or `Object.values` for such a task.

Comment: You have to loop through them to get the data , If thats your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to understand what is your desired output that well, but if you want to get the values of the JSON (and not knowing the keys) you can use one of the following:

```
Object.values(yourJson));

Object.keys(yourJson).map(key =>x[key]);
```

You can also check this one:

```
Object.entries(yourJson)
```

Answer (score 0):

that code is not in a correct JSON string format.
if change to

```
   ' {
  "-LIDMHr69GLnq1Pyzt6o": {
    "author_avatar": {
      "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jWM4ghUG930/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/q3nLLgvfOAs/photo.jpg",
      "initials": "UH",
      "selection": "image"
    },
    "author_name": "AB",
    "image": "/assets/images/icons/23.png",
    "last_modified": 1542827537242,
    "owner_id": "HauqBY5dDtP0RFhrF1DvEDuFv812",
    "team_id": "private",
    "title": "this is test1"
  },
  "-LJU_KEYGDv7hRHQ2ABo": {
    "author_avatar": {
      "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jWM4ghUG930/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/q3nLLgvfOAs/photo.jpg",
      "initials": "UH",
      "selection": "image"
    },
    "author_name": "AB",
    "image": "/assets/images/icons/23.png",
    "last_modified": 1542827549341,
    "owner_id": "HauqBY5dDtP0RFhrF1DvEDuFv812",
    "team_id": "private",
    "title": "this is test2"
  }
}'
```

you can use JSON.parse method to make it Object

```js
const data = '{
  "-LIDMHr69GLnq1Pyzt6o": {
    "author_avatar": {
      "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jWM4ghUG930/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/q3nLLgvfOAs/photo.jpg",
      "initials": "UH",
      "selection": "image"
    },
    "author_name": "AB",
    "image": "/assets/images/icons/23.png",
    "last_modified": 1542827537242,
    "owner_id": "HauqBY5dDtP0RFhrF1DvEDuFv812",
    "team_id": "private",
    "title": "this is test1"
  },
  "-LJU_KEYGDv7hRHQ2ABo": {
    "author_avatar": {
      "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jWM4ghUG930/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/q3nLLgvfOAs/photo.jpg",
      "initials": "UH",
      "selection": "image"
    },
    "author_name": "AB",
    "image": "/assets/images/icons/23.png",
    "last_modified": 1542827549341,
    "owner_id": "HauqBY5dDtP0RFhrF1DvEDuFv812",
    "team_id": "private",
    "title": "this is test2"
  }
}';

const parse_data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(parse_data);
```

Comment: This ... I wish JSON was originally named as TDIF, that would've reduced the missuse of the term radically. OP doesn't have JSON, they have a JS object.